# Knockout data binding with jQuery JSON ajax response issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, knockout.js

I have an example working on which is working with static JS based JSON formatted data but when I parse same data through Ajax it does not work.

**HTML CODE**:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>File Name</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: attachments">
      <tr><td data-bind="text: Filename" /></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**This is my JS code**:

```
function testAjax(handleData) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'form2.php',
            type: "post",
            data: '',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                handleData(data);
            },
            error:function(data){
                alert('Failed');
            }
        });
}

function localData(){
    var data = [{"Filename":"f8.doc"},{"Filename":"f3.doc"}];
      return data;
}

$(function () {
  var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.getAttachments = function() {
        testAjax(function(output){
            var arr = [];
            $.each(output, function (i) {
                arr.push(new product(output[i]));
            });
            return arr;
        }); 
        /*var test = localData();
            var arr = [];
            $.each(test, function (i) {
                arr.push(new product(test[i]));
            });
        return arr;*/
    }

    self.attachments = ko.observableArray(self.getAttachments());

    self.refresh = function() {
      self.attachments(self.getAttachments());        
    }
  };

  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
var product = function (data) {
    return {
        Filename: ko.observable(data.Filename)
    };
};
```

In this example code you can see a function named "localData" (It is commented). It contains JS based formatted JSON data set. But when I parse same data using ajax call using "testAjax" function. It has below code and results.
**Code**:

```
$data = array(
            "0"=>array(
                "Filename"=>"f8.doc"
            ),
            "1"=>array(
                "Filename"=>"f2.doc"
            )
            );

$encode = json_encode($data);

echo $encode;
```

**Results from Ajax**:

```
[{"Filename":"f8.doc"},{"Filename":"f2.doc"}]
```

Both "testAjax" & "localData show results alert(data.Filename) when I do in "product" before "`return {Filename: ko.observable(data.Filename)};`" But Ajax does not show data on page wile other local JS based formatted shows which is very strange to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your local data example, when you initialize `self.attachments`, the data is already here so there is no problem.

In the ajax example, you can't expect the data to be returned, that is why you use a callback (`handleData` here).

You need to first initialize your `attachments` observableArray, and then update it:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.attachments = ko.observableArray();

  self.getAttachments = function() {
      testAjax(function(output){
          self.attachments.removeAll();
          $.each(output, function (i) {
              self.attachments.push(new product(output[i]));
          });
      }); 
  }

  /* no more needed, call getAttachments directly
  self.refresh = function() {
    self.attachments(self.getAttachments());        
  }*/
};
```

Comment: @UMI oops, forgot to replace `arr` in the each loop. Answer updated, can you try again?

Comment: Worked like a charm, bundle of thanks :) But I have another thing to get confirmed. Please visit this URL for another example to auto refresh the data I made changes as you asked in another example into this one but it is not working [link](http://dev.ejuicysolutions.com/demo/umer/knockout/test.php)

Comment: Another thing happened in rectified code. It worked first time when page visited but you see there is a button to refresh the data so when I click that button data get empty and shows nothing.

Comment: @UMI Why do you need another function to refresh data when it just call getAttachments? Notice I put a removeAll in the getAttachment which you can remove